# How can I turn off customErrors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I'm having problems with this code; I'm building an app which will talk to a service running on a server via .net remoting, when I try to send a text over to the service so that it can be processed and sent, my code throws an exception with the following message;

> System.Runtime.RemotingException: Server encountered an internal error, for more information, turn off customErrors in the server's .config file

Could anyone help me figure out how to turn off customErrors please?

********EDIT*********************
This is a windows service! not a WCF Service!

stack trace is here;

> exception rethrown at [0]:
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessagereqMsg,IMessage retMsg)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&msgData,Int32 type)
>       at GsmComm.Interfaces.ISmsSender.SendMessage(String message,String destination)
>       at Hermes.Form1.SendSMS_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\mydirectory\Form1.cs   line 76

I'm using a 3rd party library called GSMComm to achieve this.

offending code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
// Get object and send message
try
{
    string url = string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}/SMSSender", txtServer.Text, int.Parse(txtPort.Text));
    ISmsSender smsSender = (ISmsSender)Activator.GetObject(typeof(ISmsSender), url);
    if (!chkUnicode.Checked)
        smsSender.SendMessage(txtMessage.Text, txtNumber.Text);            // Standard message
    else
        smsSender.SendMessage(txtMessage.Text, txtNumber.Text, true); // Unicode message
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Message Sent!";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{


    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This should be posted on ServerFault as it's a IIS configuration question, not a programming question.

Comment: But I'm not using IIS

Comment: Which server are you using? the message "Server encountered an internal error, for more information, turn off customErrors in the server's .config file" is an IIS standar message...

Comment: Really? that's odd because this is a windows service accessed over a LAN using a TCP connection, AFAIK IIS doesn't need to be implemented does it?

Comment: Ok, you can be calling it from a Windows Service, but you are calling on the other side to a Web Server, that error comes from the server, there is where you must do the change

Comment: Well the way i'm getting it to work is that there's a winforms app on the client side, which talks to this service, but the winforms app is giving this error you see, I'm sorry I didn't make that clear earlier

Comment: Maybe that Windows Forms application is hosting the core IIS?

Comment: I can't see how that's possible because I don't have IIS installed on the machine the winforms app is on

Comment: oh wait, I have IIS express, is this where I need to look for the problem?

Comment: IIS is part of the operating sistem, there exist a "IIS hostable core" feature which is installed by default (or can be installed as libraries with your app). Else, can you post the other app's code?

Comment: I see! so i should be looking in my documents/IISExpress/config?  and yeah of course, the entire namespace?

Comment: Maybe or maybe not, it depends on how it's being hosted, take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/hostyourownwebserverusingiis7.aspx

Comment: going back to my original question then, How can I disable custom errors? this might help in debugging the program

Comment: If it's a hostable core and uses the standar mechanism it should have a file named ApplicationHost.config in the app folder, there you must add a customError tag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I've tried that but the error still comes up as it does now

Comment: Did the app had the ApplicationHost.config file? and also, is there any Web.config file?

Comment: there's no web.config, but there is applicationHost.config, I've inserted the following <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>   
    </system.web>

Comment: but nothing's happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54801/discussion-between-gusman-and-reece).

Answer (score 1):

What type of web server are you using to host your service?

If you are using IIS, you can either modify the web.config file in the root web application directory:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1267844.aspx?Web+Config+customErrors+mode+Off+

or do it through IIS manager:
[How do I turn off custom error handling in IIS for my web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356484/how-do-i-turn-off-custom-error-handling-in-iis-for-my-web-site)

If you are using a different web server to host your service, see the documentation for instructions on how to disable it.

Comment: I'm not using a web server, I'm using TCP to access the service over a LAN